# Iterable Deque NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, deque

I am attempting to create an Deque class (Stack/Queue that can be added to and referenced at both ends) by implementing a doubly linked-list format.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
```

public class Deque implements Iterable {

```
Node first;
Node last;
int size;

public Deque()
{
    first = null;
    last = null;
    size = 2;

    first.next = last;
    last.prev = first;
}

private class Node
{
    Node next;
    Node prev;
    Item item;
}

private class ListIterator implements Iterator<Item>
{
    private Node current = first;

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return current.next != null;
    }
    public Item next()
    {
        Item item = current.item;
        current = current.next;
        return item;
    }
    public void remove()
    {
        /* not supported */
    }
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    if(first == null&&last == null)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public int size()
{
    return size;
}

public void addFirst(Item item)
{
    Node oldfirst = first;
    first = new Node();
    first.item = item;
    first.next = oldfirst;
    oldfirst.prev = first;
    size++;
}

public void addLast(Item item)
{
    Node oldlast = last;
    last = new Node();
    last.item = item;
    last.prev = oldlast;
    oldlast.next = last;
    size++;
}

public Item removeFirst()
{
    Item item = first.item;
    first = first.next;
    size--;
    return item;
}

public Item removeLast()
{
    Item item = last.item;
    last = last.next;
    size--;
    return item;
}

@Override
public Iterator<Item> iterator() 
{
    return (new ListIterator());
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Deque<Integer> deque = new Deque<Integer>();
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        deque.addFirst(i);
        deque.addLast(9-i);
    }

    for(Integer i : deque)
    {
        StdOut.println(i);
    }
}
```

}

When I run the code, I get a NullPointerException when it tries to do first.next = last; I can understand why, but I'm not sure how to fix it without breaking the list. Any solutions? Is it perhaps unnecessary to use a doubly linked format (i.e. remove the prev reference Node altogether)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You avoid NullPointerException by avoiding access to uninitialized variables.

In that particular example, leave out the:

```
first.next = last;
last.prev = first;
```

in your constructor and use defensive programming and check for null if it could be uninitialized, before accessing a variable.

For example in your addFirst method:

```
public void addFirst(Item item)
{
    Node oldfirst;
    if (first != null){
        oldfirst = first;
    }

    first = new Node();
    first.item = item;

    if (oldfirst != null){
        first.next = oldfirst;
        oldfirst.prev = first;
    }
    size++;
}
```

etc.

By the way, is this a learning exercise? If not, Java library does have Deques ready to use, including linked list:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. And yes, this is for an assignment that has strictly determined that I cannot use any libraries outside of the ones given.

Answer (score 1):

How is your size beginning at `2`? It should be `0` until you add an `Item`.

You initial conditions should be that both `prev` and `next` are `null`. When you add a single item, then size should be `1` and both `prev` and `next` should point to that object.

Answer (score 1):

When the Deque is empty, there is no "next" and "previous". It is completely empty. There would be "next" and "previous" only as soon as there is data.

So when you initialize the Deque, you should not attempt to assign a `prev` and `next` to `null` references. The fact that they are `null` indicates that there's nothing there, so of course there is nothing that comes previously or after it.

And of course, the size should be zero.

Then, in your `addFirst` and `addLast` methods, you should handle the case in which your `first` and `last` are null. In that case, you have to initialize them both to the same value, where its `next` and `prev` are both `null`. And set the size to 1.

Only proceed as you did (add item, correct the linkage) if the item in `first` or `last` respectively is not null.

And remember to check for `null` in your `removeFirst` and `removeLast` methods as well.

**Short version**: the case of an empty list is special. You should start with an empty list. You should check for this special case in your `add` and `remove` methods.